# Handling stack overflow with more recursion, and it worked

Tags: java, recursion, try-catch, stack-overflow

I found this code block in [the Javagony article on esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Javagony/Brainfuck_Reduction):

> ...In Javagony, the most common way to replicate loops is through recursion. If your loop has too many steps, you will get a stack overflow error, however, this can just be caught. So, to create a loop, we can start with a function that calls itself, and a try catch.
>
> ```java
> public void loop() {
>    try {
>        loop();
>    catch (StackOverflowException /* sic */ e) {
>        loop();
>    }
> }
> ```

Alright, so I know you *should not* "catch" the `StackOverflowError`, as many questions asked before me has already concluded; but I just cannot help get curious about what *could* happen if you just try to catch it? Will it grant you infinite recursions or will the JVM just breakdown and explode?

Anyway, here's what I have written:

```java
public class Javagony
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        loop();
    }

    static int n = 1;

    public static void loop()
    {
        System.out.println(n);
        n++;
        try
        {
            loop();
        }
        catch (StackOverflowError _e)
        {
            loop();
        }
    }
}
```

I then ran it with `java Javagony.java`. It had been a while since then, and the numbers just keep scrolling. It has now reached 4072342 (in comparison, the same programme without try catch block dies on ~40000) and is still going on. But how could this even happen? Doesn't `StackOverflowError` indicate that the resources have been exhausted, and the maximum capacity of function calls has been reached already? Why simply catching and ignoring it keeps the recursion going on?

Ps. Process has been interrupted, please don't worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alright, so I know you *should not* "catch" the `StackOverflowError`, as many questions asked before me has already concluded;

Generally speaking, you should not catch it, because it's not ordinarily something you can recover from.  You can't, generally, even rely on wrapping and rethrowing it.

> but I just cannot help get curious about what could happen if you just try to catch it? Will it grant you infinite recursions

No.

> or will the JVM just breakdown and explode?

No.

When there is no room on the stack, you cannot successfully invoke any methods or constructors.  That's pretty crippling, and generally speaking, if you try to recover from it then you're likely to just get another `StackOverflowException`. However, when a method terminates, including by throwing a `StackOverflowException`, a little stack space is freed up, so you might then be able to do a little something.

Now consider your particular example.  At the bottom of the recursion, some invocation of `loop()` throws a SOE.  The parent invocation catches it, and in the handler tries recursing again.  There is every reason to expect that that also will throw SOE, which will escape to the next level up.  But now *that* recursive call handles the exception, and it has enough stack space to get in one more iteration.  When that throws, it is handled one more level up, which now has space for *two* more iterations (each of which starts fresh with respect to exception handling).  And so on ...

That does not give you infinite recursion, but it does greatly magnify the overall number of successful executions of the payload  you can get before an SOE finally bubbles all the way out of the top-level call.

In fact, the total number of times you can expect to execute the payload scales exponentially in the amount of available stack space.  You don't need to have that much stack space before that affords more total executions than you could ever use.

Answer (score 1):

Try tracking the level of nesting:

```
public class Javagony
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        loop(0);
    }

    static int n = 1;

    public static void loop(int l)
    {
        System.out.println(l+":"+n);
        n++;
        try
        {
            loop(l+1);
        }
        catch (StackOverflowError _e)
        {
            loop(l+1);
        }
    }
}
```

it's not getting any further in the recursion and using up more stack, trying to do so generates the exception again. When it reaches the limit, the code sort of flails around in place.

So no, catching the exception does not allow you to use more stack space than the limit. The recommendation against catching it comes from the assumption that you are unlikely to have a sensible way of recovering from this condition.

Comment: It is not achieving any greater recursion depth, but it *is* getting a lot more successful executions of `loop()`.  And that's because no, it is not just flailing around at the bottom of the recursion.